# Why does gunicorn not see the corrent environment variables?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

On my production server, I've set environment variables both inside and outside my virtualenv (only because I don't understand this issue going on) including a variable `HELLO_WORLD_PROD` which I've set to `'1'`.  in the python interpreter, both inside and out my venv, `os.environ.get('HELLO_WORLD_PROD') == '1'` returns `True`.  In my settings folder, I have:

```
import os

if os.environ.get('HELLO_WORLD_PROD') == '1':
    from hello_world.settings.prod import *  # noqa
else:
    from hello_world.settings.dev import *  # noqa
```

Both prod.py and dev.py inherit from base.py, and in base `DEBUG = False`, and only in dev.py does `DEBUG = True`.

However, when I trigger an error through the browser, I'm seeing the debug page.

I'm using nginx and gunicorn.  Why is my application importing the wrong settings file?

You can see my gunicorn conf [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/xnWC2PMx)

Thanks in advance for your patience!

Comment: *How* do you set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `sudo service gunicorn start` to run gunicorn.  [The problem is service strips all environment variables but TERM, PATH and LANG](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/44378).  To fix it, in my `exec` line in my gunicorn.conf I added the environment variables there using the [--env](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#raw-env) flag, like `exec env/bin/gunicorn --env HELLO_WORLD_PROD=1 --env DB_PASSWORD=secret` etc.